# Parse reports no registered devices for push notifications [Unity Android]

Tags: android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, notifications, push

I am trying to implement push notifications in Unity Android, I've completed the Quick Start and have done everything I can find out to do, but when I try to do a test push using the "Test" button on the Quick Start page, I get the message "Can't find any registered devices yet...".  No errors or messages appear in the Parse logs, just this on the Quick Start page itself just below the "Test" button.

I have installations in the "Installation" table.  I've even added code to my app to subscribe to channels (I've tried various names, as well as an empty string ""), and these subscriptions appear in the Installation table for those installation records.

When I go to initiate a push from the Push page on the dashboard, it correctly lists the number of devices that will be targeted by the push, but none of my devices receive anything, and it shows that 0 pushes were sent.  And I keep receiving the "Can't find any registered devices yet..." message on the Quick Start page.

I even tried building the Push sample app, found some things wrong with it which prevented it from even running on the device, but I cannot get it to even register an installation, much less receive a push notification.

I have been working on this for over a week now, and I'm desperate for some help.  I really need to know the reasons why Parse would be reporting there are no registered devices despite the presence of installations.

Details:
Parse 1.6.0
Unity 5.1.0.f3